# Does the DLC for Lara Croft & TGOL have trophies?

Tags: achievements, ps3, lara-croft-the-guardian-of-light

I was just wondering if the DLC for Lara Croft and the Guardian of Light offers any new trophies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is NO! [Here](http://forums.eidosgames.com/showthread.php?s=e2d318e7b20712130f6c1444029ef826&t=115021) is the thread on the official forum.